# PostgreSQL: Select rows until sum-reduction of a single column reaches over a threshold

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, distinct

I would like to write a query that takes rows from an ordered table, simultaneously aggregating one column's value until said aggregated value meets a desired threshold.

An additional criteria is that the violating row which passes the threshold should be included in the query results.

I have looked for other solutions done in PostgreSQL, leading me to creating the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY amount DESC) AS running_amount
    FROM public.orders WHERE price = 0.09) AS t
WHERE t.running_amount <= 15;
```

The issue with this query however is that it represents a PostgreSQL window query, which skips the aggregation of a columns value over all rows if the columns value at a given row is not unique.

Window queries unfortunately do not support taking into account the consideration of distinct-valued columns.

Some alternatives I heard for still making this possible would be through creating a PostgreSQL function, though I have no idea where to start for this sort of aggregation query.

If anyone has any ideas or know-how, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a unique column (primary key) to the `ORDER BY` clause of the window function, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY amount DESC, id) AS running_amount
    FROM public.orders WHERE price = 0.09
) AS t
WHERE t.running_amount <= 15;
```

In the lack of a unique column you can use the system column `ctid.`

---

You can use `UNION ALL` to get the violating row which passes the threshold, e.g.:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY amount DESC, id) AS running_amount
    FROM public.orders 
    WHERE price = 0.09
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE running_amount <= 15
UNION ALL (
    SELECT * 
    FROM cte
    WHERE running_amount > 15
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved one problem for making the window work. What about getting the violating row which passes the threshold?

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot hahah :).

Answer (score 4):

If you want the final row (the one that crosses the threshold), you have two relatively simple choices.  My preference is:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY amount DESC) AS running_amount
      FROM public.orders
      WHERE price = 0.09
     ) o
WHERE o.running_amount - o.amount <= 15;
```

The alternative is a windowing clause:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY amount DESC
                               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                              ) AS running_amount
      FROM public.orders
      WHERE price = 0.09
     ) o
WHERE o.running_amount <= 15;
```

Comment: Turning the first query to WHERE o.running_amount - o.amount <= 15; actually works for all test cases I made! I'll make an answer explaining my observations as to why your first query is the best answer.