# Query smallest number of rows to match a given value threshold

Tags: sql, postgresql, ecto

I would like to create a query that operates similar to a cash register. Imagine a cash register full of coins of different sizes. I would like to retrieve a total value of coins in the fewest number of coins possible.

Given this table:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 3 | 500 |
| 4 | 500 |
| 5 | 1000 |

How would I query for a list of rows that:

- has a total value of AT LEAST a given threshold
- with the minimum excess value (value above the threshod)
- in the fewest possible rows

For example, if my threshold is 1050, this would be the expected result:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 5 | 1000 |

I'm working with postgres and elixir/ecto. If it can be done in a single query great, if it requires a sequence of multiple queries no problem.

Comment: Which criterion is more important? 1) The smallest excess, or 2) The minimum number of rows.

Comment: How many rows does the table have? Potentially you are looking at 2^rows combinations. It could take for the query an enormous amount of time to explore and assess all the combinations. For example, if the table has 40 rows, we are talking about 2^40 cases; that's 1 trillion combinations.

Comment: @TheImpaler the table will eventually be huge. Millions of rows. If we have to chose between minimum excess vs minimum rows, I'd say less rows is probably going to be more important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a go at this myself, using answers from previous questions:

- [Using ABS() to order by the closest value to the threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592209/find-closest-numeric-value-in-database)
- [Select rows until a sum reduction of a single column reaches a threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492040/postgresql-select-rows-until-sum-reduction-of-a-single-column-reaches-over-a-th?rq=1)

Based on @TheImpaler's comment above, this prioritises minimum number of rows over minimum excess. It's not 100% what I was looking for, so open to improvements if anyone can, but if not I think this is going to be good enough:

```sql
-- outer query selects all rows underneath the threshold
-- inner subquery adds a running total column
-- window function orders by the difference between value and threshold
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        i.*,
        SUM(i.value) OVER (
            ORDER BY
                ABS(i.value - $THRESHOLD),
                i.id
        ) AS total
    FROM
        inputs i
    ) t
WHERE
    t.total - t.value < $THRESHOLD;
```